# The basis for additive subgroup is discriminant-invariant

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

i.e. given bases $\{\beta_{i}\}$ and $\{\gamma_{i}\}$ for S additive subgroup of number field K (degree n over $\mathbb{Q}$), then $disc(\{\beta_{i}\})=disc(\{\gamma_{i}\})$.

any hints?

Is that because any algebraic number can be made into an algebraic integer

Answer (score 1):

Hint : there is a $p\times q$ integral matrix $P$ such that $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_p)=P(\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_q)$ and a $q \times p$ integral matrix $Q$ such that $(\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_q)=Q(\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_p)$.
  What can you say about the products $PQ$ and $QP$ ?

Comment: same determinant. so they divide each other.

Comment: You can say much more. For example, apply $Q$ to the equality $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_p)=P(\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_q)$

Comment: inverse of each other so done. how did we use the additive subgroup